# JSP Pagination using jQuery

Tags: jsp, pagination

I am setting the results as a List in the request parameter and I created a results page in JSP which displays all the results in same page.

My requirement is to paginate the results retrieved from servlet. I am puzzled in what way I can do it.

The pagination UI should look like this:

```
< Prev 1-25 Next>.
```

Can someone please guide me how could I accomplish this? Is there any api to do it, or do I have to change the way of approach in retrieving the results from servlet to JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are displaying all the data in the form of tables?If so then use `datatables`,this is the best plugin there is using Jquery

There is demo here http://jsfiddle.net/upenrao/HEDvf/7/light/

This is the official site http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a tutorial for you to do `Datatables` with jsp- servlet. [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2013/01/jquery-datatables-and-java-integration.html)