# How to create a transparent border using CSS in a subclass?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to create a transparent border around the page number 1 shown below in the image. I've created a subclass span tag so that I could target only that element but it seems not be working. I found some similar question saying to create a space in the CSS but still it is not working.[image]

Like the one below.

[image]

HTML (Please ignore jsp tags)

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}">  <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>'/>
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> | Page <span class="pageNumberBorder">{5}</span> of {6} | <a href="{3}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>'/>
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </span>'/>
```

CSS

```
.pagelinks .pageNumberBorder {
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssadat/321dan34/)

Comment: that isn't html. and are you saying you want a border that looks like the 2nd image with a box around "1"? Because your current code is just the number - looks like your 1st image. If you want it to look like the 2nd image, that isn't a transparent border.

Comment: I've already mentioned in my question to ignore the jsp tags. pagelinks and pageNumberBorder are the span classes which can be styled using css. If it is not a transparent border then what it is? I assumed it is just a border.

Comment: Your Fiddle is nowhere close to replicating what your issue is? Can you check the output window

Comment: loll, obviously it won't. I want to create it how can you see it in my fiddle. Fiddle is just showing the working that I've written but it is not working.

Comment: Your questions says "create transparent border" which means we all assume that the rest of the pagination part is working, which is obviously not the case

Comment: See, I am not asking anything about pagination. I want o create the border  that is my issue. And on the CSS part of my question I am trying to style it but it not working. Don't worry about the pagination.

Comment: Do you want an actual border or just some space after the 1?  If the former - the border is there, just transparent

Comment: Maybe it's not working because it's transparent? Give it a colour perhaps... https://jsfiddle.net/wt82vxkz/1/

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/321dan34/4/

Comment: Got it, thanks Coker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border in the seccond Picture isnt Transparent. Remove it

```
.pagelinks .pageNumberBorder {
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

It will work now: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dqtcdm7/)

But an a Border around a Page Number suggests an Input Field for changing the Page. If you dont have this implemented i would not use a Border there.

For [JSP Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24504762/8086920) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24504762/8086920)

Comment: @nocolasmeier. Your JS Fiddle is not showing the border at all.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I used a child selector instead of creating a new class:

```
.pagelinks > span {
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/321dan34/2/

P.S. I made the border red, to see that the code works, 'transparent' property hides the border.

Comment: What difference does this make? you are just making a less efficient selector by removing the class

Comment: @Pete How is creating and loading two classes into memory more efficient than working with one class?

Comment: css selectors work from right to left so your selector is saying select me all spans in the page, now filter me out the ones that are a direct child of pageLinks, whereas using 2 classes you will only get all items with the second class - which I'm guessing will be a lot less elements than all the spans in the dom - try a bit of research: https://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: @Pete Ok, I see now. I though once the class is found in the DOM, no further search takes place.